# Using fetch() to fetch data with a specified field

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am building an app in react-native (and native-base).
I am creating the database using ruby on rails (mysql2). I have a table categories with cid and cname. I am using the following code to fetch all data from this table. This fetches all the data from the categories table.

```
fetchData() {
     let lurl = 'http://192.168.43.92:3000/categories.json';
     fetch(lurl)
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => { this.setState({ categories: responseJson}); })
     .catch((error) => { console.error(error); });
   }
```

How can i fetch a specific field for example the field with cid=1 (Select * from categories where cid=1);.

Also how can I insert into this table using the fetch funtion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse `categories.json` file if it's a static file. If not, you should write some backend or some local storage solution to query the category with the given id.

`fetch` is a library used for making http requests. In order to insert/query the table, you should have a backend service. In order to get more clear answers, you need to clarify your question.

If local storage is satisfactory, then I suggest using `realm`. You can read it's docs at https://realm.io/news/introducing-realm-react-native/

Like I said, you need to provide more details.

Comment: I do have a backend running and the fetch request works fine. I just need to fetch data with a specific id.